# jQuery Ajax not executing

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-post

Greeting.

I have made this jQuery Ajax call, which doesn't seems to be executing.

It does handle the `.live()` call, but not the `.ajax()` call.

Any ideas?

Source of ajax.js:

```
$("#action_login").live("click", function() {
    var username = $("#login_form input.username").val();
    var password = $("#login_form input.password").val();
    alert("Username: " + username + "/nPassword: " + password);
    $("#login_form .status").ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/login.php',
        data: {
            'username': username,
            'password': password
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("error" + data);
        },
        dataType: dataType
    });
});
```

It does call the first `alert();` command, with the right value from the inputs for username and password, but after that nothing happens.

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: $.ajax should be called without an element, remove $("#login_form .status") from in front of it.

Comment: Also note that .live has now been deprecated and replaced with .on.

Comment: `dataType: dataType` = is this actually set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#login_form .status")` is the call to the `$` function with `"#login_form .status"` as parameter.

It returns a very different object than `$`, and it doesn't have any `ajax` function.

So, replace

```
$("#login_form .status").ajax(
```

with

```
$.ajax(
```

Comment: Beat me like a ginger step-child :)

Comment: ... or simply check the answer comments :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
$("#login_form .status").ajax
```

With

```
$.ajax
```